# Generating Release Notes using AWS CodeCommit and Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-codecommit, semantic-release, release-notes

I'm currently using AWS CodeCommit for git repo version control and Amplify to build/serve my files.

I need to create release notes, as an exported file, when a merge is done against my main branch and preferably update my package.json version for the project.

I've looked at `release-please` and `semantic-release` they seem to be widely used with GitHub, but, like other solutions I keep running into walls such as a `GITHUB_TOKEN` being required, which CodeCommit doesn't do. That or it creates a tag for the release BUT CodeCommit supports tags but not releases.

Is there an AWS soliton for this?